# I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my PC, I put it on USB but nothing happens

Tags: software-installation

I need help figuring this out. I think I'm doing something wrong. I need to install Ubuntu on my PC but nothing happens when I restart I followed the tutorial.

Comment: You should [edit] your question add more details. What Ubuntu version? Which tutorial? Is your USB stick bootable? Did you actually make your PC boot from the USB stick (and not from the HDD)?

Comment: Maybe the following link will help, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

Answer (score 2):

Which tutorial did you follow? Did you have any issues in one or more steps?
Basicly the following steps lead to a working Ubuntu:

1. Download Ubuntu (it's an .iso-file): for most users it's the [LTS](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) version
2. make a bootable USB stick from the .iso-file: sounds hard, but only requires a few clicks; Tutorial for doing it under [Windows](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0), [Mac](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#0), [Ubuntu](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0)
3. change the boot order of your PC: You need to tell your PC to boot from the USB stick instead of your hard drive: [tutorial](https://www.howtogeek.com/129815/beginner-geek-how-to-change-the-boot-order-in-your-computers-bios/)
4. Save changes in BIOS, plug in your brand new bootable USB stick and restart. The Ubuntu-setup should start now and explain you all the rest.

Comment: I followed the tutorial from the Ubuntu website and I pushed the download button for desktop then I saved that to my usb then I did an advanced reset and loaded my usb on bootup but nothing happened the computer just restarted

Comment: @Jessica Sounds like you now have a USB stick with one big *.iso file on it. That won't work. Have a look at step 2 in the above answer.

Comment: @JessicaHannah that's right. Just copying the .iso file won't do it. You need to kind of "burn" the .iso file on the usb stick (like a CD). Just follow one of the tutorials in step 2. (depending on the OS from where you want to do it).